# Error during JSON file download

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to download JSON data into a JSON file using below mentioned code but the code just gives me a blank Internet Explorer. I need code to download JSON file without having any event raised at user interface.

```
 var dataUri = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(JSONData));
    var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataUri);
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", "CarData.json");
    downloadAnchorNode.click();
```

Comment: `just gives me a blank internet explorer` If you're doing web development, try not to use an ancient obsolete browser.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, You mean i should not be using Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: No. This is 2018, not 2013

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without having any event raised". Most browsers (even modern ones) are going to show a dialog asking where to save the file...

Comment: IE11 and under does not support it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @CertainPerformance, When i set Microsoft Edge as default browser and set breakpoint at the same code, breakpoint does not hit but with internet explorer 11 breakpoint hits. In Google Chrome my page does not even shows up. I am using Visual Studio as IDE.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan, What i meant was i have to execute the code by without raising any event like button click, specificaly for executing that part of code

Comment: You aren't even inserting the anchor into the DOM to be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a blank page because you aren't inserting the anchor node into the DOM.  Consider the following snippet.  Even if you remove the `download` attribute, you will be taken to a page with JSON data on it.

```js
var JSONData = {
  foo: "bar"
};

var dataUri = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(JSONData));
var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');

downloadAnchorNode.innerHTML = "Click";
downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataUri);
downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", "CarData.json");
document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode);

downloadAnchorNode.click();
```

Here it is without the `download`:

```js
var JSONData = {
  foo: "bar"
};

var dataUri = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(JSONData));
var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');

downloadAnchorNode.innerHTML = "Click";
downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataUri);
document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode);

downloadAnchorNode.click();
```

Additionally, as others have pointed out, [IE does not support the `download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thank you for such an awesome reply. I  do have another following question i.e. If i have multiple js objects like [0] [object], [1] [object], what shall be the approach to write such js objets in JSON file